# Best way to expose http listening port in java based desktop application

Tags: java

I have a desktop application that is written in Java and that I have source code for.
I want to launch a process in this application based upon when I click a button in my web application.

I'm thinking that the browser can fire off a HTTP call to the desktop application on the loopback address.  The application will only listen on the loopback address thereby preventing other machines from talking to the application.

If I take this route, I have to host some kind of http listener in my java desktop application.  What is the best way to do this?

I have considered embedded tomcat and jetty, but I'm wondering if those aren't overkill or less secure due to a larger feature set, and I could run a http socket listener with something simpler.